# Rota dinâmica Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

estou com a seguinte dúvida.
É correto criar uma rota dinâmica para retornar minhas views, ou tenho que criar uma rota para cada controller e retornar a devida view?

Exemplo do código que estou utilizando

arquivo de rotas

```
Route::get('/{url?}/{url2?}/{url3?}', 'UrlController@getUrl');
```

controller

```
public function getUrl($url = null, $url2 = null, $url3 = null) {
    if (isset($url3)) {
        return view($url . '.' . $url2 . '.' . $url3);
    } elseif (isset($url2)) {
        return view($url . '.' . $url2);
    } elseif (isset($url)) {
        return view($url, ['name' => 'Romullo']);
    } else {
        return view('home');

    }
}
```

Este código me retorna exatamente a view que é digitada na url ou gera a página de erro corretamente. Porém me surgiu a dúvida dentre tantos artigos que li. Isso é correto ou não?
Devo realmente criar rota por rota para cada controller e view ou posso chamar dinamicamente?

Comment: Se você pode fazer algo com 10 linhas e nunca mais precisar mexer (a não ser que mude muito o código), pra que fazer em 50? Talvez em algum momento você queira algo mais específico, por exemplo, que uma rota passe por uma validação ou algo assim, nesse caso pode criar uma rota específica e dar prioridade a ela

Comment: Por que você não utiliza o recomendado pela documentação? Me parece que esse modo de escrever gera um código difícil de se manter conforme o número de rotas cresce.

Comment: Não acho que exista A ou B, mas casos e casos. Mas não tenho como discordar do @Marabesi, que é muito importante pensar na legibilidade do código tanto quanto desempenho ou quantidade de linhas.

Comment: Não pode fazer assim, pois, vai haver choque de rotas ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer com esse código. Acho que vai ser melhor você fazer rotas separadas. Dependendo do que você quer fazer ficaria mais fácil ate de você criar uma factory com essa rota dinâmica e usa essa factory para mandar o cara para o controller corretor.

Do jeito que esta fazendo o seu código vai ficar complexo conforme for crescendo e ai vai ficar mais difícil de dar manutenção nele e para outras pessoas contribuírem também.